# Post image with raw json?

Tags: nodes, services

Using `Content Type: application/json` I tried like:

**EDIT:**

```
{
 "type": "article",
 "title": "Test article with image1",
 "body": {
 "und": [{
     "value": "test body!"
   }]
  },
 "field_image":{
 "und":[{
  "fid":{
  "filename": "bar.jpg",
  "target_uri": "sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/bar.jpg",
  "filemime": "image/jpeg",
  "file":        "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQAAAFzBAMAAABC179RAAAAD1BMVEUYooorZrPZwVO3Sd0M9BOSfwC2VwFIl7c9aAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==",
   "filesize": "12345"
       }
     }]
    },

  "language": "und"
 }
```

**Problem:** `Image` is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `file` resource to upload the file first; that will provide you with a `fid` (file ID), which gets attached to the field on the node. The payload for that request might look something like:

```
{
    "filename": "foo.jpg",
    "target_uri": "bar/foo.jpg",
    "filemime": "image/jpeg",
    "file": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKQAAAFzBAMAAABC179RAAAAD",
    "filesize": "12345"
}
```

And then to attach it the field your existing code will change to something like:

```
"field_image":{
  "und": [{
    "fid": [FILE ID RECEIVED FROM FILE SERVICE HERE]
   }],
}
```

Comment: Should I post first part first,so that I can get `fid`,again I have to post the second one with `fid`,what is `target uri`?is it like `/site/default/files/images`?

Comment: Yeah exactly, but it uses the public schema uri instead of an absolute path (the `public://` bit). Might be worth experimenting with just making a single call and using the first object in place of the object with "fid" in it - services might be clever enough to create the file for you when it's attached to a node, I'm not sure

Comment: Posting first part I got response like this `{"fid":"13","uri":"http://www.drupal1.com/formnode/file/13"}`

Comment: Yep that's spot on, you can use the fid to attach the file to the node now. But I would try the one-request approach too just in case

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: The node object needs to be wrapped maybe? `{ "node": [current object] }`

Comment: How can I do it for `one-request`,any suggestion or reference?Code updated.